# Best practice for creating a C++ Dll to be marshalled in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling

I have to write a C++ Dll to wrap an existing C++ Dll so it can be declared in C# because the existing C++ API is just too complicated (functions returning pointers to unions within structs within structs). Is there any best practice for this? For instance:

- What's the best way of declaring a string from C++ to C#?
- Is it better to have C++ functions using pointers or references?

Comment: People voting to close - can you leave a comment explaining why?

Comment: Because your question appears to be too broad.

Comment: Expose the functionality as a COM class. I think that can be more easily consumed from .NET.

Comment: I'm just asking for best practice - a book, an article, a blog post...

Comment: @parsley72 Asking for off-site resources is OT as well.

Comment: Using the C++/CLI language extension to write a managed wrapper for a native C++ class is the boilerplate solution.  Fast and simple, directly usable from any managed language.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many functions you wish to export and if you wish to export them only to c#.
If you answer yes to one of these then I recommend using swig as functions will get generated for you automatically

Here is a link 
http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html